# access [object Array of Byte] objectGUID value from ADODB.Recordset for an Active Directory query

Tags: javascript, active-directory, activex, adodb, recordset

I am using JavaScript and ActiveX to query Active Directory. Everything works great but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access the values of an object of type `[object Array of Byte]`. I know the values are there cause I can see them in IEs debugger window.

The code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var recordSet;
            function doIt()
            {
                var ADConnection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.connection");
                var ADCommand = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Command");
                ADConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 600;
                ADConnection.Open("Data Source=Active Directory Provider;Provider=ADsDSOObject");
                ADCommand.ActiveConnection = ADConnection;
                ADCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 10000;
                ADCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = 2;
                ADCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 600;
                ADCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = false;
                ADCommand.Properties("Chase Referrals") = 96;
                ADCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;

                ADCommand.CommandText = "<GC://DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(anr=imthenachoman));distinguishedName,objectGUID;subtree";

                var recordSet = ADCommand.Execute;

                var distinguishedName = recordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").value;
                var objectGUID = recordSet.Fields("objectGUID");

                // this works
                alert(distinguishedName);

                // according to IEs debugger, objectGUID is a of type [object Field]
                // objectGUID.value is [object Array of Byte] but I cannot figue out how to access each value in the array                

                recordSet.Close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="doIt(); return false;">do it</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of IEs debugger window showing the data is there. I just cannot figure out how to access it...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a smart man. I was able to figure out the answer literally 5 minutes after posting this.

```
objectGUID = (new VBArray(objectGUID.value)).toArray();
```

This will convert the `[object Array of Byte]` to a JavaScript friendly array of integers.